# Error message using TinyMCE-GWT with SmartGWT

Tags: gwt, tinymce, smartgwt

I'm using TinyMCE-GWT with SmartGWT, and when TinyMCE is loaded, an "Application error" alert is appearing:

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): ed is undefined
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor127.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:292)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:546)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Otherwise, the editor is displayed, and it seems to work flawless. But I clearly, can't let it that way. Any clue?

**Edit**

Here a piece of my code:

```
Window popin = new Window();
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
final TinyMCE editor = new TinyMCE();
editor.getConfig().setTheme("advanced");
canvas.addChild(editor);
popin.addMember(canvas);
```

**Edit 2**

Some more infos: The editor is displayed, but doesn't work properly. When I retrieve the content in my GWT code, it's an empty string, even if I entered something in the editor. So it's not only a focus issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ed` usually refers to a tinymce instance. i suggest you try finding the relevant place in the code and make sure ed is an editor instance. `tinymce.activeEditor` usually is a good replacement if an editor is not available (`ed`)

Comment: I added a piece of my code to make it clearer. I have no variable, attribute or paramter called ed, actually...

Comment: I have found related code in the TinyMCE source itself. Is it what you meant?

Comment: what i mean is that you you need to find the piece of code that calls ed. and ed is not called from javascript here, your java uses it

Comment: As I said, I have no variable, attribute or parameter called ed, and neither can I find anything like that in the source code of TinyCE-GWT http://code.google.com/p/tinymce-gwt/source/browse/

Comment: I edited the question in order to add the throwed exception: 
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): ed is undefined

Comment: i suggest you have a closer look at the code refferred to in that stack trace to find out at what place in the code the error comes from. Noone will be able to guess where your error comes from.